# How to make model unique for each user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is probably easy to do but I am not sure how to do it.

I have a user model for a website that tracks TV show watching.

I also have a season model and an episode model.

I want a user to be able to mark a specific season or episode as watched.

How can I make it so a season or episode be unique to each user?

For example. All seasons and episodes start unwatched. If one user were to mark season 1 of a show as watched and another  user were to login how could I make it so it wouldn't show up as watched for that user as well?

Thanks!

Comment: usually you store the user `id` along side the show, episode, season info in the database.

Comment: You can create a record of this by creating a new model, let's call it `episode_watched`. A new record will be created whenever a user marks the episode as watched. In this record, you will have the user_id, tv_show_id and episode_number.

Comment: Is there a term for doing something like this that I can do more research about online?

Answer (score 0):

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :episode_item, :season_item,:scope=>[:user_id]
```

If you want `User` to have only one possible certain episode or season watched.

But not to show to users episodes, watched by other users - then use `build` method with foreing key `user_id`

```
@season_item = current_user.season_items.build
```

Remember, that `Season` and `SeasonItem` should be separate models - when users add some season to 'watched', they obviosly do not create new season of show.